# Data Formatting pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to enter a line of code that creates a row for the index `31'st January 1995`. I am unable to get the row to look like `31/01/1995` and instead the output is `1995-01-31 00:00:00` .

My original data in a dataframe called MainData

I am trying to add a row at the top for 31st January 1995 in the same format as the data below.

[image]

My code is

```
MainData.loc[pd.to_datetime('31/01/1995',format='%d/%m/%Y'),:] = [100 for number in range(7)]
MainData
```

[image]

Please let me know if there is a way to reformat this to `31/01/1995`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I need the index to look like "31/01/1995" and not the way it is in the output. How do I do that?

Comment: I have no idea. Please make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: MainData is the main dataframe where I am trying to add a row with "31/01/1995". There is no df.

Comment: I think it's better write a function that convert `datetime` type into `string` and then apply it on your column.

Comment: Am editing my query to provide further information

Comment: I did that but is there a way to convert  date index to an actual dateformat because I think keeping it in a string will create problems when sorting the data?

Comment: I converted my "date" Index to a column and changed the format to a datetime format and then added a row with 31st Jan 1995 adjusted to a date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Making the data look more normal by removing the first column index level
MainData = MainData.rename(columns=MainData.iloc[0])
MainData = MainData.iloc[1:]
#Re-adjusting the Index to a datetime format
MainData['DateAdjusted'] = MainData.index
MainData = MainData.reset_index(drop=True)
MainData['DateAdjusted'] = pd.to_datetime(MainData['DateAdjusted'],dayfirst=True)

#Just renaming the Column and converting the index back to Date
MainData.rename(columns={'DateAdjusted':'Date'},inplace=True)
MainData.index = MainData['Date']
del MainData['Date']

#Defining the date for the row I want to add
InitialDate = "31/01/1995"
format_str = '%d/%m/%Y' 
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(InitialDate, format_str)
print (datetime_obj.date())

MainData.loc[datetime_obj,:] = [100 for number in range(7)]
MainData = MainData.sort_index(ascending=True)
```